# How to search. pdf links on a given web page?

Tags: pdf, search, rss

I have this rss page with a lot of links to .pdf files.

The thing is to search for certain strings inside those. pdfs, without the need to open them one by one, and do the search for each one, because they do are a lot!

Does anyone knows a way we may have to search inside those pdfs?

Any ideas?
Any browser extension ?
Any RSS feed that allows this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use Google.

`filetype:pdf site:http://xyz.com/abc <your keyword(s) here>` would do the job for you. You just need to find the common domain in the PDFs. By that I mean that if there are two PDFs on the page that are located at http://xyz.com/abc/1.pdf and http://xyz.com/abc/2.pdf then you can use `site:http://xyz.com/abc`. Only `site:http://xyz.com` would work too, but would bring you all the PDFs that it finds on the website.

So you want to be specific.

Comment: This will of course work only if search engines have been allowed to index those files.

Comment: @Karan I am pretty sure that is the case here.

Comment: *Might* be the case here perhaps (I didn't bother to verify), but my comment was of course an addendum to your answer since people other than the OP will be reading it later and in their case things might be different and so they can't *always* use Google.

Comment: Doesn't return any results. Here's the site in question with the exact command used: `filetype:pdf site:http://dre.pt/sug/notificacoes/rss.asp?id=212 Guarda Braga` Guarda and Braga being the keywords.

Comment: OK, then either it is not allowed to index those files, or these keywords are not there in the files. Try `filetype:pdf site:http://dre.pt Guarda Braga`

Comment: Sir, you are a google master. ;) Cheers. I added OR and other operators to better refine the search. 5 starts. Not sure however, if the index is accurate in time, is it ? Or it will only list keywords WHEN the .pdfs are scanned by google bots?

Comment: lol, there's no mastery.

Answer (score 0):

download the files first, then search

`find /path -name '*.pdf' -ls -exec pdftotext {} - \; | grep "your query"`

Comment: Thanks. I didn't intend to download them each time I do a search. But that command is indeed nice. :)